# byte[] with ASCII values to string to int

Tags: c#, byte, ascii

So someone took int value, converted it to string then converted it to ASCII values and then finally to byte[] with inconsistent length 1 - 4 bytes.

e.g. 100 -> "100" -> { 49, 48, 48 }.

Now I need that int value and I did it like this:

{ 49, 48, 48 } -> '1' + '0' + '0' -> "100" -> 100

```
                switch (header[25].Count)
                {
                    case 1:
                        hex = "" + (char)header[25][0];
                        amountOfData = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        hex = "" + (char)header[25][0] + (char)header[25][1];
                        amountOfData = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        hex = "" + (char)header[25][0] + (char)header[25][1] + (char)header[25][2];
                        amountOfData = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        hex = "" + (char)header[25][0] + (char)header[25][1] + (char)header[25][2] + (char)header[25][3];
                        amountOfData = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16); ;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

but maybe there is better solution...

EDIT: sorry for not mentioning that, but header is `List<List<byte>>`

Comment: `int result = array.Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 10 + a - '0');`

Comment: what is the type of `header[25]`? is it a `byte[]`? a `List<byte>`? or...?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that, but header is ```List<List<byte>>```

Comment: and now I realized that I know one of the dimensions needed so it's ```List<byte>[]``` but it doesn't matter

Comment: side note: `List<byte>` seems like a very unusual choice here; not saying it is "wrong" as such - just: very unusual

Comment: it's because I get a lot different parameters in one data frame. Some of them are 1 byte long, another is 11 bytes long. I don't want to make my array byte[26][11] and check zeros. And only few of this parameters have fixed length.

Comment: my bad, there's no need to set array second dismension on beggining, but still it's easier with ```List```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Encoding/GetString method to convert bytes of different encodings (e.g. ASCII in your case) to a .NET string:

```
var input = new byte[] { 49, 48, 48 };
var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input);
var result = int.Parse(str, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: you can bypass the `string` step to avoid some overheads, btw (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use library functions to parse from byte-like data to primitives; you're talking about ASCII, which means that `Utf8Parser` will work fine for us (all ASCII is also valid UTF8, although the reverse is obviously not true); normally, we would expect that `header[25]` is a `byte[]`, a segment there-of, or some other raw binary source, but: ultimately, something like:

```cs
var span = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(header[25], 0, header[25].Count);
if (!Utf8Parser.TryParse(span, out int amountOfData, out _))
    ThrowSomeError(); // not an integer
```

If `header[25]` is something less convenient (like a `List<byte>` - I notice that in your example, your `header[25]` has a `.Count` not a `.Length`, which suggests it isn't a `byte[]`), then you can always either `stackalloc` a local buffer and copy the data *out*, or you can peek *inside* the list with `CollectionMarshal.AsSpan<T>(List<T>)`, which returns a `Span<T>` from the underlying data:

```cs
var span = CollectionMarshal.AsSpan(header[25]);
if (!Utf8Parser.TryParse(span, out int amountOfData, out _))
    ThrowSomeError(); // not an integer
```

---

As a runnable example that just shows the API:

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers.Text;

Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[]  { 49, 48, 48 };
if (!Utf8Parser.TryParse(span, out int amountOfData, out _))
    throw new FormatException();
Console.WriteLine(amountOfData); // 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your code and came to this solution with its help:
```int amountOfData = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(header[25].ToArray()), 16);```

Comment: Actually I came to this ```ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(header[25].ToArray(), 0, header[25].Count); Utf8Parser.TryParse(span, out int amountOfData2, out _);```, but it returned ```44``` from ```{ 52, 52, 68 }``` and not ```44D``` as it should

Comment: @Imm in the original question, you were trying to parse an integer; if you are now dealing with strings, then that's just `anyEncoding.GetString`; in modern runtimes, the API accepts spans. For example, `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(span)`

Comment: oh, right, sorry about that, I overlook this fact even though it was in my original solution